# Byte Buddy: Dynamic field value

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am working with byte buddy and I want to get values for all private fields in my intercepted class.
I know that I can do something like this

```
   public static boolean intercept(@Advice.FieldValue("fieldName") String fieldName)
```

My issue is that my interceptor works on multiple classes so the fields will vary.
Is there a way to get all fields value for an intercepted class? Or maybe call the getter of those fields in my interceptor?
The reason why I'm looking for @FieldValue is that I am using byte buddy on build time and I want to avoid having to use reflection on run time to get the field values or invoke the getter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your own bindings for such purposes. This allows you to resolve a value once and extract it again and again.

The issue is that an array or a list cannot be represented as a conpile time constant, that implies allocation on each access. Therefore it is hard to create a general purpose mechanism.